# my .htaccess edit is crashing site

Tags: php, .htaccess

htaccess so I could use php5.3 but it is crashing the site. Something wrong with the php line I think because when I load my site now, it displays chunks of my raw php codes. I don't know how to fix it. Would be great if someone can help.

```
<FilesMatch "\.php$">
AddHandler x-httpd-php53 .php
</FilesMatch>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 years"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Are you sure you have php 5.3 installed and linked on your server?

Comment: it seems like the issue is i have 2 version of php installed...how do i fix it?